# (Probably simple) Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the solutions to the diff eqn:
$A\dot{x} + \cos(x) - 1 = B$ subject to boundary conditions $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} x(t) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} x(t) = C$,
where $ A, B, C$ are constants?

Comment: Try writing $\dot{x} = dx/dt$, separate them to two sides, like $\displaystyle A\frac{dx}{1-\cos(x)} = B\,dt$, and integrate on both sides.

Comment: @MathChief Shouldn't it be $\displaystyle A\frac{dx}{B+1-\cos(x)} = dt$

Comment: Are these limits when $t$ (and not $x$) goes to $\pm\infty$? And are the signs of $A$, $B$ and $C$ known?

Comment: @Michael, that's right, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Separation of variables gives  $ dx/(p + q\cos x) = dt$  for some $p$ and $q$ and this can be integrated on any (maximal) interval for which the left side is defined, to give $F(x)=t$ for an explicit function $F$.  On such an interval $F$ will be monotonic and with range from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$; the solutions of the differential equation are $x(t) = F^{-1}(t+K)$ for constant $K$.  Boundary behavior at infinity should be $x(\pm \infty) = \pm \infty$ according to the sign of $p+q\cos x$ in the interval.

If these calculations are correct then there is no freedom to define the boundary conditions at infinity, only at finite times.

Comment: In the expression $x(\pm\infty)=\pm\infty$ the first $\pm\infty$ should be replaced by the bounds of the maximal interval of integration of the differential equation.

Comment: @Didier: yes, thanks. What I should have written is that the boundary behavior is $F(\pm \infty) = \pm \infty$ which is, except for the sign, independent of $A, B$ and $C$.  Describing this in terms of $x$ (i.e., the maximal interval) does utilize the constants in the problem statement.